# Rendering a div based on a condition

Tags: visualforce

I need to render a  tag based on the value of **layoutObj.colOneInputType.Required**.
But i cannot use the outputpanel rendered attribute for the implementation of the same! Any work arround?

here is my code snippet.
the problem statement here is that i want to add a red vertical bar as used by salesforce for denoting required textareas whereas for non mandatory text areas i dont want to display the bar.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(layoutObj.colOneInputType.dataType=='textarea',true,false)}">
<div class="testrequiredInput">
  <div class="testrequiredBlock"></div>
  <apex:inputTextarea rows="3" styleclass="clsInputTextArea srm_clsDynamicInputTextArea" title="{!layoutObj.colOneInputType.Tooltip}" id="textArea"  value="{!layoutObj.colOneInputType.value}" onChange="checkVisibility('{!layoutObj.colOneInputType.isChangeNeedRefresh}');"   disabled="{!isViewMode}" onkeyup="validateMaxLength(this);"/>
</div>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!If(layoutObj.colOneInputType.URLInfo!=null,true,false)}">
<input type="button" class="urlButtonDeactivated1" title="{!layoutObj.colOneInputType.URLInfo}" style="margin-left:2px;cursor:pointer" onmouseout="this.className='urlButtonDeactivated1'" onmouseover="this.className='urlbutton1';" onclick="window.open('{!layoutObj.colOneInputType.URLInfo}','_blank','height=500,width=1000,left=170,top=100,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=no')"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using style attribute like this inside the div:

```
style="{!IF(layoutObj.colOneInputType.Required, 'display:block', 'display:none')}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Why can you not use an  tag?

If you add `layout="block"`the output panel get rendered as a `<div>`

If you add `layout="non"` the output panel does not output to the page but its contents do

If you add `layout="inline"` the output panel gets rendered as a `<span>`

So it seems to me if you use output panel with layout="none" then it should meet your needs

Another way to do it is using jQuery and some scripting:

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.req_blk').each(function(){

                showRedMark(this, true);

            });

        });


    function showRedMark(a, b){


            if(b){
                $(a).parent("td").prepend("<div class='requiredBlock'></div>");
                $(a).parent("td").contents().wrapAll("<div class='requiredInput'/>");
            }else{
                $(a).prev().remove();
                $(a).unwrap();
            }
    }
</script>
```

When you render the tag use:

```
class="{!IF(layoutObj.colOneInputType.Required,'req_blk','')}"
```